# Launch a AfterEffects rendered in background with cmd update

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to find scripting code that allows me to open a CMD in Windows and lauch AE render of the current project queue in background.

Also, if possible, to get the output back in that cmd window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After Effects has a seperate executable for the render engine.
Have a look at this article from Adobe for some usage examples and an overview of the commands.

http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html

```
aerender -project c:\projects\project_1.aep -comp "Composition_1" -output c :\output\project_1\project_1.avi
```

As you define the output file yourself you already have the path available. As soon as the command finished you know your file is done rendering and you can process it further.